# How do I find B-R5RB on the world map?

Tags: eve-online

I got no search results in the world map control panel. I know it will be hard to get there but that's the whole reason I signed up for a trial.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first step is to open the People & Places dialog, the icon for that can be found in the Neocom (the black bar on the left side), the icon is marked by a red circle in the following screenshot

[image]

Type B-R5RB into the search field there and hit "Search"

[image]

Right-click on the result "B-R5RB" in the Solar Systems section

[image]

Click "Set destination" in the context menu

[image]

You should now see a route planned in the top left of your screen, it should look something like in the next screenshot (though not exactly, as I'm almost certainly starting from a different system than you)

[image]

Right-click on the "A" next to "Route" and set the route planner to "Prefer Shorter". You're going into Null-sec, so you might as well take the shortest route.

[image]

Dock out and look at the overview window. The gate you need to take is marked in yellow as in the following screenshot.

[image]

Just jump through each yellow gate and you'll arrive at your destination at some point.

I'll warn you though that as a completely new player the odds of actually arriving there are not exactly in your favor. You're going into null-sec space, every other player can kill you there without facing any consequences. You're also going to a rather famous site at the moment, so there is a pretty good chance some players are waiting for new players like you that want to visit there, and they will kill you before you know what happened. So don't be disappointed if you don't make it to B-R5RB in one piece.

If you want to try it, buy one attack frigate of your race (Condor, Slasher, Atron or Executioner), place as many `Nanofiber Internal Structure I` as you can put into your low slots, and pray. You can't fly the type of ships that can evade bubbled camps in null-sec yet, so I won't lie about your chances to make it there, I consider them rather slim. But you might get lucky, and those frigates are pretty cheap.

Comment: I want to add a point: you should be able to fit a _10MN Afterburner I_ in a med slot. If you are stuck in a bubble, turn it on, you'll be out of it and free to warp way faster. As long as there are no Interceptors, you'll be the fastest ship in those bubbles and you'll have greater chances to get your as out of there.

Comment: @Lysarion There are many things one could do to evade or escape gate camps. I targeted this towards a completely new player without a single skill learned.

Comment: Well, to use an 10mn afterburner 1, you just need the skill afterburner. If he took enough time to get enough isk for a T1 frig & nanofibers, he can easily run one more mission to buy the skill, the AB and use it. And it will drastically increase his survival chances.